# How to allocate Local Work Item sizes in OpenCL

Tags: opencl, opencl-c

I've set up a convolution kernel in OpenCL to convolve a 228x228x3 image with 11x11x3x96 weights to produce 55x55x96 filters.

My code without allotting localWorkSize works perfectly, but when I do allot it, I start getting errors

My questions are therefore,

1) How many threads are being launched when I set localWorkSize to NULL? I'm guessing it's implicit but is there any way to get those numbers?

2) How should I allot localWorkSize to avoid errors?

```
//When localWorkSize is NULL

size_t globalWorkSize[3] = {55,55,96}; 

//Passing NULL for localWorkSize argument 

errNum = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue, kernel,3,NULL,globalWorkSize, NULL,0, NULL,&event);

//WORKS PERFECTLY
```

```
// When I set localWorkSize

size_t globalWorkSize[3] = {55,55,96}; 
size_t localWorkSize[3] = {1,1,1};

errNum = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue, kernel,3,NULL,globalWorkSize, localWorkSize,0, NULL,&event);

//ERROR CONTEXT CODE 999
```

I'm just trying to understand how many threads are created when localWorkSize is Null and GlobalWorkSize is described

Comment: localWorkSize always needs to divide globalWorkSize evenly (0 == globalWorkSize % localWorkSize). Always try to pass a localWorkSize that fits the number of processing elements in a compute unit. Also, make sure you always stay within the boundaries of what is returned by clGetDeviceInfo with `CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_ITEM_SIZES`

Comment: Yes! This works, but somehow, the time taken is still about the same

Comment: I have no idea what your kernel does, but it seems 55x55x96 is a relatively small problem to solve. If you have multiple read/writes, then using local memory might speed things up a little instead of always accessing global memory.